# How do I put line break in Django template tag?

Tags: django

So I'm making an app that basically gets three keywords from the user. The user has to input three keywords in three separate fields, named 'kw1', 'kw2', 'kw3'. Then I've tried to render the data with template tag, like below. 
*I have the template tags in script tag, because I had to put them in for loop for some reason.

```
...
{% for form in myKeywords %}
{
contents : "{{form.kw1}}<br>{{form.kw2}}<br>{{form.kw3}}",
}
{% endfor %}
...
```

I wanted to have line breaks between keywords, but in my page it shows the raw(?) text itself with the br tag in between.
What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```html
    {% for form in myKeywords %}
    {
    contents: {{ form.kw1 }}<br>{{ form.kw2 }}<br>{{ form.kw3 }},
    }
    {% endfor %}
```

rather than writing the tag in a string, because HTML doesn't recognize it's tag 
 in a string.

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is, it's in my script tag, so I have to put the whole value in the quotation mark.

Comment: You can use it without quotations too. It should work. Does it say any error?

Comment: No, it doesn't say any error, but I see nothing on my page if I remove the quotation marks.

Comment: I see red underlines on the brackets though.

Comment: Could you share the snippet if possible?

Comment: ```$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultDate: '2020-05-14',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: [
                {% for i in events %}
                {
                    title: "{{ i.kw1}<br>{{i.kw2}<br>{{i.kw3}}",
                    start: "{{ i.when|date:'Y-m-d' }}",
                    end: "{{ i.when|date:'Y-m-d' }}",
                },
                {% endfor %}
                ]
            });
        });```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Is this how I share the snippet? Sorry I'm a beginner and not familiar with tools :(

Comment: replaced `"{{ i.kw1}<br>{{i.kw2}<br>{{i.kw3}}"` with `{{ i.kw1 }}<br>{{ i.kw2 }}<br>{{ i.kw3 }}` and tried?

Comment: Yes I have. It doesn't show anything on the page if I remove the quotationmarks...